# How to diagnose problem of terminal output truncation

Tags: terminal

A problem has developed on one of my systems in which terminal output is getting truncated. When I login via SSH for instance and I run For `ls -l` command only 3 or 4 lines are shown, then the screen hangs.  When I connect to the terminal directly, ie via VNC the same  happens.

However when I connect via `wetty` for instance  everything is fine.

Any ideas of what the cause could be, or how to diagnose what is happening?

Comment: If you attempt to replicate this by using netcat, does it persist?  Do you have logs?  Have you tried looking at a packet capture to see what is going on?

Comment: @DopeGhoti: Can you use netcat to log in to a server that doesn't support telnet (but only ssh)?

Comment: Yes.  `ssh` into the remote host, run `nc -l 23456`, then on your local host, run `ls -l / | nc host.example.com 23456`.  You should see the output of `ls` on the remote host's terminal.

Answer (score 2):

I have had this happen when the MTU of some link in the path was misconfigured.  Check the configured packet sizes at both ends and as many of the intermediate hops that you have access to.  On Linux systems, the ifconfig program will display the info you need.

Comment: This may be the most likely reason. When I connect from another location the problem isn't present. I will try from the original location which was a wireless hotspot to see if the problem only occurs there.

Comment: On the other hand, the same problem should have occurred when I connected with via the console, so that also needs investigation.